# Stata combining datasets in memory

Tags: append, stata, frames

I'm using census data across multiple years. For each year, the dataset is laid out completely the same in terms of structure and content (i.e. the same questions are asked of respondents and their answers are laid out in the same way across years). I want to import multiple datasets, apply changes to each, and then combine them.

To illustrate what I mean, I imported the 2018 data (the frame is titled 'cps18') and removed three specific rows. I then used `frame change` and imported the 2019 data, called 'cps19,' and applied similar changes. When I use `append using cps18`, the console returns "file cps18 not found."

From what I can find online, it seems that the `append` command is used for combining datasets on the disk with the frame in memory. But what if I have two or more frames in memory? Is there a way to combine them?

Comment: Combining the dataset in memory with another dataset (.dta file) is a matter for `append` in this case, and nothing to do with frames, as I understand it.

Comment: In that case, if I have two frames, how would I go about combining them? Append is not working for me, as described above.

Comment: Not expert on frames, but I have heard that they can’t be appended. Do ask on Statalist if you don’t get a better answer.

Comment: Will do! I suppose I'll find a workaround in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

past self! You can write a loop to perform the same actions across multiple files. Let's say you have cps17.csv, cps18.csv, and cps19.csv. We can write a loop to import each file, make the necessary changes, and then append:

```
  cwf default // revert to default frame

  clear 
  tempfile cpsdata
  save `cpsdata', replace empty
    
  forval y = 17/19 {
    import delimited cps`y'.csv
        
    g newvar1 = oldvar1 + oldvar2 // sample change
    destring year, replace // sample change
        
    append using `cpsdata', force
    save `cpsdata', replace 
  }
```

Comment: In your example, `egen` would be better as `gen`, as that's illegal code for `egen` even if you have `oldvar1 oldvar2` as variables in the dataset.

Comment: Good catch! I was originally going to display an egen example, but changed to gen at the last moment. Edited to fix this mistake.